# Matrix form equation from recurrence equation

Tags: matrix

```
 Table[Coefficient[\!\(
 \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = \(-10\)\), \(10\)]\((I\ n\ w\ 
   \*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n\)]\ 
  \*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\  + \ 
  \*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\ \ nu\ n\ w\ 
 \*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\ \((
  \*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n + 1\)]\  - \ 
 \*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n - 1\)])\)\  + \ 
 \*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n\)]\ 
  \*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\ )\)\)+ nu theta Subscript[c, 1] w/2 ( (z + z^-1)/2 + 
  1/(4 I) nu (z^2-z^-2)),z,n]==0,{n,-5,5}] //MatrixForm
```

I want this equation to be written in matrix form as AX=b and then i can diagonalise the A to calculate X. Note that d_{-6}=0  and d_{6}=0

Answer (score 2):

Let us start with your equation (without the wrapper "MatrixForm"):

```
eq = Table[Coefficient[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = \(-10\)\), \(10\)]\((I\ n\ w\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\  + \ 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\ \ nu\ n\ w\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\ \((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n + 1\)]\  - \ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n - 1\)])\)\  + \ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(n\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(n\)]\ )\)\) + 
     nu theta Subscript[c, 1] w/2 ( (z + z^-1)/2 + 
          1/(4 I) nu (z^2 - z^-2)), z, n] == 0, {n, -5, 5}];
```

The variables are:

```
vars = Table[Subscript[d, i], {i, -6, 6}];
```

Now we can get the searched matrix and b by:

```
mat = Coefficient[eq[[All, 1]], #] & /@ vars   // Transpose
b = (mat . vars ) - eq[[All, 1]] // Simplify
```

To check if we did not make a mistake, we can calculate:

```
mat . vars - b == eq[[All, 1]] // Simplify
(*True*)
```